# How to solve this Reactjs Eslint warning about 'index' is defined but never used

Tags: arrays, reactjs, iterator, eslint

Feels like a mistake to me how can I not have an "index" when iterate a map.
Any ide?

[image]

Comment: replace it by `_`

Comment: Remove it. Its an optional param. It's not saying you don't have an index, its saying you've never referenced the variable so its unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the index returned from the map function. You're declaring 'id' inside of it and assigning a value returned from "uniqueId" somewhere else in your code.

This is not a bug.

If you don't want to see the warning, you could:

- not use "index", since in fact you're not using it.
- replace it with `_`, that way eslint will understand that you're discarding that parameter

Edit:
As pointed by Brian Thompson, you probably want to use the index anyway, to get a unique id without having to create one by yourself:

```
Resume.article.map((element, idx) => {
  articles.push(
    <div className="column" key={idx}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eslint warn about using index for "id" so I use "uniqueId"

Comment: **Do not** use random numbers for the `key`. If you truly do not have a unique identify on the object itself, just use the index of the array. Using a random ID will most likely cause `Article` to un-mount and re-mount each render. This is bad.

Comment: Updated my answer to include this note

Answer (score 1):

You're not using/referencing `index` anywhere, so just remove it from the parameters. You don't need it.